# Toolbar TBSTYLE_FLAT issue

Tags: windows, winapi

[image: TBSTYLE_FLAT]

If I create a toolbar and add the TBSTYLE_FLAT flag my toolbar ends up with a black background and the buttons behave funny, without the flag all is well except the separators don't show so the question is how do I use the TBSTYLE_FLAT properly so that the separators show but the background behaves as it should?

```
dwExStyle = nul
dwStyle = WS_CHILD + TBSTYLE_LIST + TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS + CCS_NODIVIDER + TBSTYLE_FLAT
```

Edit: If I take out the TBSTYLE_FLAT and then send a TB_SETSTYLE message with TBSTYLE_FLAT before the window is shown then everything looks OK but the toolbar places itself at the bottom of the window and clicking a button shows the button rec to still be at the top of the window?

```
 TBSTYLE_FLAT = 0x0800;
 TB_SETSTYLE = 0x438;
```

Comment: You need to set the TBSTYLE_FLAT flag before your toolbar become visible .

Comment: I have done so, I left out WS_VISIBLE and do manually set it visible after receiving a valid handle for the toolbar

Comment: Are you sure it's not something *else* in your code?  I have seen lots of code that uses those exact styles that doesn't end up with a black background.

Comment: What Ive done now is set the dwStyle to WS_CHILD only then before the toolbar is shown set all the styles with TB_SETSTYLE and it works OK, no idea why the styles wont work correctly, for me, with the createwindowex though.